# Automatic motion blur in video editor?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, final-cut-pro, vegas-pro

Is there an alternative to the automatic motion blur in After Effects for Adobe Premiere, Sony Vegas or Final Cut?

I use it mainly to sync text/image animations with sound cues, however After Effects is not a real-time editor and is difficult to work with several layers.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google: RSMB (Real Smart Motion Blur)

I know it is available for after effects and Sony Vegas, not sure about final cut.

Note: It dramatically increases your render time, but it is definitely worth it

Comment: Thank you, I'm using it right now. Definitely a time saver!

Comment: The Answer is a bit short :) Could you please elaborate? Why I should use it?

Comment: @poor Short, yet appropriate to the question. I think the best way to see why it is the best out there is to look it up YouTube! :)

Answer (score 1):

Motion from Apple has a setting for Motion Blur on all projects. [This section](https://help.apple.com/motion/mac/5.0/en/motion/usermanual/#chapter=6%26section=2%26hash=apple_ref:doc:uid:Motion-UserManual-90915BMP-1013584) of the documentation explains how to set it (in the project settings). (It's under "Motion Blur and Reflection Settings".)

Once the project setting is set, you may also need to turn it on in the canvas to see it while editing. [See here](https://help.apple.com/motion/mac/5.0/en/motion/usermanual/#chapter=2%26section=8%26hash=apple_ref:doc:uid:Motion-UserManual-90915GUI-1018983) for information on turning it on in the Canvas. (It's under the section named "Render pop-up menu.")

Motion renders a lot of stuff in real time, though turning on Motion Blur will slow it down. You can always set the number of samples to something low-ish (like 4 or 8) while working and turn it up for renders.

I believe that if you're using a Motion template in FCP that it will render the Motion Blur if you set the canvas to "Better Quality" playback.

Comment: Thank you, Motion is another vfx editor, I would to see this behavior in a standard real-time editor rather than a vfx package.